# How to set the input device for voice recognition

Tags: microsoft-speech-platform, microsoft-speech-api

Is there a possibility to set another microphone input than the systems default for recognizing speech with either the System.Speech or Microsoft.Speech on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 machines?

I surfed the docs and I have not found an obvious way. But maybe there is a workaround or maybe I have missed something?